# Encoding WEBM to MP4 in NodeJS fails with too many packets buffered for output stream

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm encoding short WEBM clips in NodeJS on GCP using fluent-ffmpeg:

```js
ffmpeg(`/tmp/${id}/clip.webm`)
  .renice(5)
  .outputOptions([
    '-c:v libx264',
    '-c:a aac',
    '-pix_fmt yuv420p',
    '-profile:v main',
    '-level 3.1',
    '-movflags +faststart',
    '-max_muxing_queue_size 9999',
    '-af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0"'
  ])
  .on('end', () => {})
  .on('error', (error, stdout, stderr) => console.log(stderr))
  .save(`/tmp/${id}/clip.mp4`);
```

This command works great for first 20-25 clips, but then it fails converting all consequent clips:

#### STDERR output

```
ffmpeg version N-47683-g0e8eb07980-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg\n libavutil 56. 24.101 / 56. 24.101\n libavcodec 58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100\n libavformat 58. 24.100 / 58. 24.100\n libavdevice 58. 6.101 / 58. 6.101\n libavfilter 7. 46.101 / 7. 46.101\n libswscale 5. 4.100 / 5. 4.100\n libswresample 3. 4.100 / 3. 4.100\n libpostproc 55. 4.100 / 55. 4.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/tmp/LbRMfZQWkZkAjShuLXcn/clip.webm':
Metadata:
Encoder : Chrome
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1366x768, SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384, 30.30 fps, 16.58 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
[aac @ 0x66ceec0] Qavg: 31427.693
[aac @ 0x66ceec0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

All clips are quite small, around 3-5 Mb each, so GCP temp folder size shouldn't be the case
I used `-max_muxing_queue_size 9999` trying to solve it, but the problem persists
Closer to the last of 20-25 clips FPS drops dramatically from normal to 3-5 FPS

Also in all cases audio starts with 3-4 sec delay for some reason:
`-af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0"` didn't solve it

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any luck? I have the same issue

Comment: @guyromb I had switched to Python and looked no further since then